# Tomar valor de una variable de otro archivo .vb

Tags: vb.net

Me encuentro realizando una página web .asp con visual basic. Tengo dos archivos ArticuloClass.vb y  Venta.aspx.vb

En ArticuloClass.vb creé una variable global a la cual le asigno un valor usando unas funciones.

```
Public AplicaDescuento As Integer
```

Lo que quiero hacer es tomar el valor que tenga desde Venta.aspx.vb. En c# es súper fácil.

Si estoy en un Form1 y quiero asignar un valor a una variable de un form2 pongo:

```
Form2.variable = 10;
```

y ya está listo, pero como realizo lo mismo en visual basic?

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Igual esto te sirve

ArticuloClass.vb
Puedes crear un sub, que al ejecutarlo, extraiga el texto del form2:

```
public sub CargarDescuento()
   Aplicadescuento = Form2.variable
end Sub
```